# Build SSH communication setup from docker container to bitbucket private repository

Tags: git, docker, bitbucket, ssh-keys, bamboo

I am having docker installed on Bamboo agent(which is AWS EC2 instance) and every time this agent is randomly picked by Bamboo to execute task.

We need to push code changes to Bitbucket private repository from docker container itself.

We cloned repository using Bamboo code checkout task on agent and copied code to docker container.
But when we try to push code from container we need to have ssh keysetup so for this we generated ssh keys on agent itself and copied .ssh folder from agent to container's root directory while building image.

As agent is going to be different everytime we are generating new ssh keys each time and so copying new keys to docker container using dockerfile.

But as to have communication between docker container(private key) and Bitbucket repository(public key) we need to upload public key to repository.

How to update this public key to bitbucket repository as everytime public key is going to be different.
Is there any other way to sort this?

Please suggest.
Thank you.